# unable to access npm says permision denied

Tags: node.js, npm, operating-system, npm-install, npm-package

first i used to be a windows user then due to academics i had to dual boot for linux operating system along with windows i used to have nodejs in windows before and use work on my projects using commands like npm and npx but after dual booting.node is working the same but i am unable to access the npm it says permission denied in powershell in **WINDOWS**

Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

- npm
- 

At line:1 char:1

- npm
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

and it says npm command is not recognized

and in command prompt it says

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

but when i run npm init and npm install in a folder only package.json and package-lock.json are installed node modules are not installed

i tried removing and downloading nodejs again but didnt worked
i also tried manually adding the environmental variables to nodejs

none of them worked please help me

**I NEED IT TO WORK IN WINDOWS BACK AGAIN **

Answer (score 0):

I used this command

```
sudo npm install -g
```